# silex index_dev.php htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, silex

I use virtual hosting and I can't change virtual host directory to myapp directory. Because I need redirect request to directory 'public' in .htaccess
My .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
#   RewriteBase /public

    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /public/images/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /public/css/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /public/js/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^ckeditor/(.*)$ /public/ckeditor/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^kcfinder/(.*)$ /public/kcfinder/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ /public/uploads/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^index_dev.php/(.*)$ /public/index_dev.php/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now my application in folder 'public' and with this settings routing at application and all css, images, js loaded fine, but  http://example.com/index_dev.php/some/path always redirect me to http://example.com/public/index_dev.php/some/path
I want make route with  index_dev.php work correctly

Comment: Instead of rewriting why don't you set your `DocumentRoot` to `/public`?

Comment: As I wrote above: "I use virtual hosting and I can't change virtual host directory to myapp directory.", I mean I can't change DocumentRoot. Do you understand?